# Rollback tab is not working in liquibase while running application no error in console out put

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

I am using

```
<rollback>
     drop table tag.
</rollback>
```

, but the given table is not being rolled back. Here is the code:

```
<rollback> <dropTable tableName="table_name"/></rollback>
```

Comment: example code<rollback> <dropTable tableName="table_name"/></rollback>

Comment: can some one assist me on my query

Comment: Please, post the whole `changeSet`. And also, is there any record in `databasechangelog` table about the changeSet you're trying to roll back?

Comment: <changeSet id="BUILD-1.2" author="build-auto">
    <validCheckSum>*</validCheckSum>
    <tagDatabase tag="BUILD-1.2" />

Comment: yes record is there in databasechangelog table

Comment: What command are you using to roll back?

Comment: Also, please think about how you ask your questions. Would you be able to reproduce the error with just the description you gave? One thing I tell people is that questions/bug reports should have three things: 1: this is what I did (steps taken, relevant configuration, etc.) 2: this is what actually happened (including output, error messages, etc.) 3: this is what I expected to happen (show how that is different than actual).
Also, here on StackOverflow, if someone adds a comment to the question asking for more code details, edit the question rather than adding it as a comment.